# Simultaneous connections MySql/C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a WCF webservice that caters simultaneous requests from different clients. The service has to communicate with mysql Db on every request. The issue that i am facing is that a large number of requests come in at a same time (about 300-400) and while communicating with MySQL 'Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts' pops up.
What i've figured out till now is that Mysql is unable to manage so many simultaneous connections and fails to cater any more and starts throwing the error. What is the best way to get around this issue?
Following is the code snippet that is called every time a requests comes in:

```
        try
        {
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query);
            command.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            long id = -1;
            int _result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (_result == 1)
            {
                 //do something
            }

            conn.Close();
            return id;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Never write `throw ex;`.  You should replace the whole `try` block with a `using` statement.

Comment: Do nothing in the catch block, except writing an event log at most. Even do not do that in the catch block. Just copy the exception details somewhere and write that event log outside the transaction. Do not throw.

Comment: Buy an expensive MS-SQL-Server license and help the Gates Foundation

Comment: To me the connection pool size could be too low. Try to pass a higher value in your connection string and the problem should go away ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How long does "//do something" take?  If it's short, I don't see a whole lot you can do to 
speed it up from the code.  If it's long, consider closing the connection before doing whatever that is (presumably error handling).

(As a side note, you should try the [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) statement instead of the try/catch block to close the connection)

edit: Also, as SLaks said, "throw;" will do the same thing as "throw ex;" except it will preserve the stack trace, which is why you should not have the "ex;" on there, but this point is moot if you replace it with using.